# Returning managed pointer from a clone method

Tags: pointers, c++11

In C++11, two types of "managed" pointer types were introduced - shared_ptr and unique_ptr. Let's now assume we have a set of classes that support a clone() method, such as foo->clone() would return a copy of the foo object. If your goal was to return a managed pointer from the clone() method, how would you allow the user of the interface to select which kind of pointer he wants to be returned?

As a sub-question, would you rather return a raw pointer from the clone() method and let the user construct either shared_ptr or unique_ptr by himself? If not, why?

Comment: You can always turn a `std::unique_ptr` into a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Yes, but the syntax is ugly and hard to maintain, especially for a complex templated class, since you need to explicitly parametrize both the unique_ptr and the shared_ptr with the same type.

Comment: Or you write one ugly `template<typename T, typename U=T> shared_ptr<U> shared_from_unique(unique_ptr<T>&& src);` helper function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard smart pointer to manage a dynamic allocation is always `unique_ptr`. By contrast, `shared_ptr` is a very specific tool with specialized features (e.g. type-erased deleter, weak pointer observers) and higher costs (virtual dispatch, locked atomic operations) that should only be used when you definitely know you want it. Public raw pointers are a taboo out of principle, and so the natural `clone` interface looks like this:

```
struct Base
{
    // must have virtual destructor to destroy through base pointer
    virtual ~Base() {}

    // non-leaf classes are abstract
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived(*this));
        // or "return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this)" in C++14
    }
};
```

(Unfortunately, we cannot use any kind of covariant return types here, since the template classes `unique_ptr<Base>` and `unique_ptr<Derived>` are unrelated. If you prefer to have a clone function that returns the derived type, you could add a non-virtual function like `direct_clone` that returns a `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`, and implement the virtual `clone()` in terms of that.)

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky: That's highly unlikely. You wouldn't want shared pointers for cloning purposes. You can always construct a shared pointer from a unique pointer later.

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky: An unrelated mechanism to *add shareholders* to a shared pointer is to use the `shared_from_this` mechanic. But that means you're not making any copies of the object at all.

Comment: I think I understand the reasoning behind always returning a unique_ptr, but mainly because there is a shared_ptr constructor that takes a unique_ptr and takes ownership of the object pointed to. I don't however like that the syntax can be quote cumbersome if the type of the object is more complex. You can either do shared_ptr< Foo< .... > >( foo->clone() ) or shared_ptr< decltype( *foo ) >( foo->clone() ), none of which are pretty or "user-friendly". The first one lacks both readability and maintainability, the second one lacks readability.

Comment: But that can be overcome with something like as_shared( foo->clone() ), where as_shared would be rather simple template function

Answer (score 0):

Something along this lines would give you the means to select the kind of smart pointer returned. Would probably be better if encapsulated in a mixin Clonable class template, for maintainability and reusability of the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {
    std::cout << "deleting Base\n";
  }

  template <template <typename ...Args> class SmartPtr>
  SmartPtr<Base> clone() {
    return SmartPtr<Base>(this->inner_clone());  
  }

  virtual void speak() const = 0;

private:
  virtual Base *inner_clone() const = 0;
};

class C: public Base {
public:
  ~C() {
    std::cout << "deleting C\n";
  }

  template <template <typename ...Args> class SmartPtr>
  SmartPtr<C> clone() {
    return SmartPtr<C>(this->inner_clone());  
  }

  void speak() const {
    std::cout << "I am C and I inherit from Base!\n";
  }

private:
  C *inner_clone() const override {
    return new C(*this);
  }
};

// End boilerplate.

int main()
{
  auto original = C{};
  // the declarations below should use auto, and are just explicitly typed to
  // show the correct return type of clone();
  std::shared_ptr<C> shared = original.clone<std::shared_ptr>();
  std::unique_ptr<C> unique = original.clone<std::unique_ptr>();

  // the declarations below show it working through conversion to a base class
  // smart pointer type
  std::shared_ptr<Base> sharedBase = original.clone<std::shared_ptr>();
  std::unique_ptr<Base> uniqueBase = original.clone<std::unique_ptr>();

  // the declarations below show it working through the base class for real
  std::shared_ptr<Base> sharedBaseFromBase = sharedBase->clone<std::shared_ptr>();
  std::unique_ptr<Base> uniqueBaseFromBase = uniqueBase->clone<std::unique_ptr>();

  shared->speak();
  unique->speak();
  sharedBase->speak();
  uniqueBase->speak();
  sharedBaseFromBase->speak();
  uniqueBaseFromBase->speak();
}
```

Compiles with gcc 4.8.1, and should in any compiler supporting variadics.

I would still prefer to simply return a unique_ptr and move the result into a shared_ptr, which would be automatic since the call to clone() is in itself an rvalue.